# Yii Relational CActiveRecords Form

Tags: php, yii

I have several tables and want to put them  on a  form.
Those tables are interdependant and are all relataed.
What is the right way to do it?

1. Use Several CActiveRecords on the form?
2. Make one CModel that encapsulate all the active records?

Comment: Use several active records on one form.  It's so easy, so why not?  I can't think of an elegant way to combine two models into one.

Comment: Made a class for that and i'm extending http://pastebin.com/70xmNKsc , i think it's elegant enough, just a method on the model that handle everything and extending from this class instead of CModel

Comment: I like it..can you make it extension, and post on YiiFramework, so that people can have their opinions, and put on github as well..:)

Comment: Just finishing the extension with tests and examples, hopely next week it will show up. It got far more complex than what i envisioned but it think it will be worth it